# running ionic generate page inside NX monorepo angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, monorepo, nomachine-nx

i am inside a NX monorepo, its working on angular.

I have installed Ionic as pre instructions given on [link](https://medium.com/@haleminh27/ionic-4-nestjs-nx-monorepo-dream-come-true-a7eb4c01a646). Ionic is working ok, But i cant use commands like `ionic generate page --project=sales-app`, i am getting error like, `An unhandled exception occurred: Schematic "page" not found in collection "@nrwl/angular".`

Please help, how to resolve this.

Answer (score 6):

the schematic that you should use is `@ionic/angular-toolkit:page`, however this require alway a module where register routes of the page

With Nx, I have not made it work and the option --skipImport not work fine in this schematics. But if you have a module correctly then run:

```
> npx nx g @ionic/angular-toolkit:page home --project=app1 --dry-run
```

Remember --dry-run its only for dump tests

Regards :)

Comment: npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add a comment in @Caxvalencia answer but since I don't have enough reputation here is an answer.

You can create a page directly with a module and routing module using the --routing option

```
npx nx g @ionic/angular-toolkit:page home --routing --project=app1 -dry-run
```